# Cleaning Up MySQL Resources Using WHERE x IN (1,2,3)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've been reading optimization routines for using an array to perform SQL functions on multiple rows through one query. My question relates specifically to PHP/MySQL.

What I've allowed a user to do in the system I'm working on is to create a product, and then to subsequently create customized attributes for said product. This question relates to the cleanup process for when a product is deleted, since product data, feature data, and feature options are all 3 stored in different tables.

This is my current clean-up routine so far:

```
$feature_cleanup = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM features WHERE feature_parent = $parent_id");
if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) $feature_cleanup[] = $assoc['id'];
  @mysql_query("DELETE FROM features WHERE feature_parent = $parent_id");
  // TODO: Use $feature_cleanup to delete feature options
}
```

My current thoughts are to simply do:

```
$cleanup_list = implode(',', $feature_cleanup);
```

Can I simply pass $cleanup_list as the IN or do I need to affix the parenthesis around it, or do I have to further process it down into a string?

```
@mysql_query("DELETE FROM feature_options WHERE option_parent IN $cleanup_list");
```

Or:

```
@mysql_query("DELETE FROM feature_options WHERE option_parent IN ($cleanup_list)");
```

Comment: Don't suppress error messages. It's a bad practice and only hurts you in the end.

Comment: I'm well aware of error message suppression risks, however those are not my concern since I have an entire routine dedicated to handling them later in the script.

Comment: You're saving error and warning processing for later on instead of dealing with them immediately? o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a [sub query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

```
DELETE FROM features WHERE feature_parent IN (SELECT * FROM features WHERE feature_parent = $parent_id)
```

Not sure if I got the Sub Query correct for your needs, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I like the simplicity in this and it seems to work with what I've already built. I will mark this as the accepted solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

"Can I simply pass $cleanup_list as the IN or do I need to affix the parenthesis around it, or do I have to further process it down into a string?"

The answer to that question is you need to wrap the IN clause in parens to delineate it as a set, including a single value.

However, if you've got values stored in different tables that all need to be deleted at the same time, you should handle that in your database itself by carefully using cascade deletes. For example, if a product is deleted, that delete should be cascaded down to featured products, etc, so that no trace of a produce is left behind dangling around. Wouldn't want a product to be featured that isn't sold. Let the database do the work.

Comment: Cascading delete... or if must be done in the application, at least inside a transaction to rollback to consistent on any failure.

Comment: Agreed on transactions. It can be dangerous to do this with cascading deletes if you aren't paying attention, but long term it's your best bet.

Comment: I've not used cascading deletes before, do you have a good primer on how to use them?

Comment: Sure, they're not too bad. You're going to need to make sure your FK's, PK's, and all that jazz are setup right, else you could be in for a world of hurt. Use something like MySQL workbench or PHPMyAdmin to make the legwork easier. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html.  And do keep in mind, this will REQUIRE you to run ALTER statements on your tables if they are already setup and running.

Comment: Thanks for the help folks. I'm going to upvote simply because I know this is the right way to go about it, but I've got to do some restructuring to get it to work this way. Time constraints won't allow for this now, but I'd like to go this route in the future!